# In C# VS2008 how to replace intA = (int)obj.GetStr("xxx"); to intA = int.Parse(obj.GetStr("xxx"));

Tags: c#, vb.net

In C# VS2008 how to replace

```
intA = (int)obj.GetStr("xxx");
```

to

```
intA = int.Parse(obj.GetStr("xxx"));
```

I have thounds of lines code have this pattern. I just want to pass compile by using some regular expression.

Comment: How did they get this way in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variation on what LBushkin suggested:

```
find: \(int\){:i\.:i\(:q\)}
replace: int.Parse(\1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try search and replace using the following regex:

EDIT: Replace the AAA, BBB, CCC values with the appropriate method names you want to match and replace. Be careful of using the :i (identifier) match predicate, as that would match any method call - which you probably don't want.

Find:  (looks for any call on any expression to GetStr)

`\(int\){.+}\.{(GetStr|AAA|BBB|CCC)}\({.*}\);`

Replace With:

`Convert.ToInt32(\1.\2(\3));`

or (as others have mentioned) replace with:

`Int.Parse(\1.\2(\3));`

Comment: Thanks LBushkin.
Actrually I want to replace all methods in the same pattern not only apply to GetStr, can you make some small change for that?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to convert types other than just int (like double, short, etc)? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Do the other methods all have a single string parameter, like GetStr?

Comment: All methods just like this pattern:
objQueueXML.AAA("//UserID");
objQueueXML.BBB("//UserID");
objQueueXML("//UserID");

Comment: Or more generically, identifier.methodname("stringparameter"). I posted a variation on this answer that seems to match any method name.

Comment: You may not want to make the RegEx to generic, otherwise you may find yourself replacing more than what you expect. I'll edit my post to include a version where the GetStr method is substituted with a list of method names you can define.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the new version either.  When you know you have a string, `int.Parse()` or `int.TryParse()` is probably more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, i totally agree  with you. So how can I convert to int.Parse()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Search and Replace?

Search for 'intA = (int)obj.GetStr("', replace with 'intA = Convert.ToInt32(obj.GetStr("'.

Comment: And you'll still have to go line by line and add a trailing parenthesis ).

Comment: Yeah, but you could always use the crazy as all heck VS regex syntax and do an easy enough replace.

Comment: i can't simply do that because intA maybe intA, intB, intC....and obj maybe obj1, obj2, obj3....

Comment: @CodeYun: add that to the question clarify it.

Comment: @Quintin: VS regex really is "special", isn't it?